# How to listen for a single field in Firebase's Android SDK

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to figure out a way to listen for a single item using the FireBase API's. So far I figured out how to query a single item using the `orderByKey` and `equalTo` functions.

I tried to do something similar for listening for a single value, but anytime I change one value it gives me the whole database items when I just want the one that was changed. I've added the `valueEventListener` and the `childEventListener`, but they seemed to do similar things.

Is there a way to listen for a single item and only return that single item?

Comment: Moses, downvoting this and voting to close because there is no code here. There is no sample of the data. And there are a [good deal of useful docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) at your disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, lets assume this is your Firebase setup summary:

```
 yourApp:
   "node": {
       "subNode1": {
          "value1": value,
          "value2": value,
          "subSubNode":{
              //....values....//
           },
       },
  "node2": { ... },
  "node3": { ... }
  //...and so on ..//
},
```

And you are trying to listen to `value2`? **If that is the case, that *is not* possible.** To access this, you need to listen to the parent node; `subNode1`, and `onChildEvent`, just get that value.

However, if you are trying to listen to `subNode1` or even `subSubNode`, **that *is* possible**. By just providing the path to this object when creating the Firebase object.

If you post more code, I will modify this accordingly to better answer your question.

### EDIT

Say you wanted to retrieve `subSubNode`. Create a Firebase reference to that and add a listener:

```
 Firebase firebase = new Firebase("yourFirebaseURL").child("node").child("subSubNode");
 firebase.addChildEventListener(new .....);
```

Comment: The latter half is what I am looking for. My level 1 nodes are the different categories of data, and my level 2 nodes are users and I just want to only listen for one user. So based on your example structure, I am looking to see if subNode1 and only that subNode changed any of its value. 

The trouble I am having right now is to see how to design a class that properly listens for a particular subNode.

Comment: What is a user? Is it an object or a single  value? like a string or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Binghammer. I was not understanding the child methods correctly. Your insight was helpful!